# Liferay 6.1 or 6.2 CE?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

We are starting to migrate our CMS to liferay.Could anybody please help me understand which version of liferay we should be going with?

Liferay 6.2 looks to be having great support for mobile devices but some posts on internet say about having bugs in 6.2 and patches being available only for EE version of 6.2?

Any quick suggestions would really help! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when you go with `CE` and you are just starting with liferay than it is always preferable to start with the latest version.

Reasons:

1. Here is a [one from Liferay Staff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125133/468763)
2. Bugs are always there, but 6.2 GA2 solves most of them and there would be other versions coming out for 6.2 which would solve more bugs.
3. If you find any bugs in 6.1, there would be no newer version for this. So it is better to go with 6.2.

Hope this helps.